# node.js http.js : TypeError: Object 200 has no method 'toLowerCase'

Tags: http, node.js

I'm learning node.js now. Whenever I ran node example.js it says

> http.js:529
>   var key = name.toLowerCase();
>
> ```
>                      ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Object 200 has no method 'toLowerCase'

is this known issue with FF and chrome.

Comment: thanks for the answers. Yes,it was old example,it used response.setHeader instead of response.write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js has nothing to do with Firefox or Chrome, except for sharing the same javascript engine (V8) with Chrome. So it's not an issue with Chrome or FF, but with one of Node.js, V8, or your own code.

The problem is probably that you passed the wrong type of argument to a function, such as a number instead of a string.

```
// For example
response.write(200);
// Will fail because 200 is a number, not a string
```

Answer (score 3):

> is this known issue with FF and
>   chrome.

Are you running node.js in the browser?. Node.js should be run as a server from the command 
line.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `name` has a `Number` value of 200. Number does not have a `toLowerCase` method. If you are expecting non-numeric values in `name`, convert it to string first `String(name).toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this message myself, using this example from [net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/):

```
// Doesn't work with node.js 0.4.7
var sys = require("sys"),  
    http = require("http");  

http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.sendHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write("Hello World!");  
    response.close();  
}).listen(8080);  

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

To get this to work, quote the 200 as deduced by @Na7coldwater and @Chandru, and correct the two function names (sendHeader() should be setHeader() and close() should be end()):

```
// Works with node.js 0.4.7
var sys = require("sys"),  
    http = require("http");  

http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.setHeader("200", {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write("Hello World!");  
        response.end(); 
}).listen(8080);  

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

And here's the current Hello World from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```